# Deepliink not working when user install the app and open FireTV

Tags: deep-linking, amazon-fire-tv

According to Amazon deeplink document if user search for a movie and open the movie, if app is installed works fine as deeplink is still there but if app is not installed then it redirect user to app install page and user click install and then open the app then in that case deeplink not destroyed according to the document, but when i have tested my Firetv App, deeplink get destroy and its launches the app normally i.e Home page of the App.

Please let me know where i have done wrong or Amazon not support it yet? but it's mentioned in document.

[image]

[image]

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/deep-linking-featured-content.html